# How to output a specific category in my view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a rails 3 blog application which has article and category "category belongs_to :article" Article has_many :category, now I have different category which have many article for instance sport category which contain all  sport article, what i want in my application layout i want to show only sport article in on div please tell me how to go about it. thank you ...

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :content, :excerpt, :title, :image, :remote_image_url 
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :category
  validates :title, :content, :excerpt,  :category_id,  presence: true
  validates :title, uniqueness: true

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history]

  def long_title
    " #{title} - #{created_at}   "   
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated according to your comments:

First step, get all the categories, let's say you do this in categories#index action:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

Now we're going to make a link to each category with that category's name in the categories#index view. When users click on a category they will be taken to that category's show page where we'll list all related articles:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category.name, category %>
<% end %>
```

We add the following in the categories#show action:

```
def show
  @category = Category.includes(:articles).find(params[:id])
  @articles = @category.articles
end
```

Then you can show all those articles by iterating over the `@articles` variable in the corresponding categories#show view. For example adding them as links in a some div:

```
<div class="articles">
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <%= link_to article.title, article %><br>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Now do the same in the articles controller for the show action:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

So basically a user will see a link that says "Sports", when he clicks on it he will be taken to a page such as `yoursite.com/categories/4` or `yoursite.com/categories/sports` if you're using `friendly_id`. Under this page all related sports articles will be listed and when they are clicked on the user will be taken to that article's show page.

Comment: yes i want to show all article in health category as i have created health category, so all article that belongs to the health i want to show them in my views..

Comment: no i want to show all article in health category as i have created health category, so all article that belongs to the health i want to show them in my views.

Comment: i don't know if i should past a site to let you see what i want becuase this issue have being holding my project for a long time

Comment: ah yes, what you wrote before the code contradicts the code itself `category belongs_to :article`, then in the code `article belongs_to :category`. Anyway my answer is how you should show all articles belonging to a category - which part of the answer you don't understand?

Comment: yes i want to show article that belongs to a category eg the health category

Comment: as I said, everything you need to do to find them is in my answer, so which part of it isn't working for you?

Comment: well i want this to show in my layout so my users can see it every where

Comment: hmm.. i got what you are try to say but i want the use to see the link of the article that belongs to sport category when he click it he should be able to see the show page of the article so he can read it

Comment: In the last step the user will see all the articles, and if he clicks on them he will be taken to their show page. Of course you need to create the show action for the article but that's very simple `@article = Article.find(params[:id])`. What you're trying to do is very simple, read some tutorials: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: no please i have read this tutorial but i am getting this confusing see just let me get it, i want to list out all article that belongs to sport category only.. and let say i have diffrent category like sport, health, etc but i want to show only sport category i dont want to show health category.. did you understand now?

Comment: I added the last bit, if you follow every part I wrote down you will have what you want, then you can tweak it to fit your needs. But I highly recommend you go over a few online tutorials, as they will teach a lot of these basic fundamentals.